# how enable work with active low and how the truthtable is valid against all inputs

Tags: decoder

Find the truth table for the outputs Y0, Y1, and Y2.[image]

Comment: No I haven;t idea about truth table

Comment: @maazawan - Hi, For assignment / homework-type questions like this, **we need to see your own work *first* (even if it is wrong)**. That is currently missing, so your question has been "[closed](/help/closed-questions)". However as explained in that link, it will be put in a queue to consider re-opening it, if you [Edit] your question, **add your own genuine best attempt, your analysis & make it clear *exactly* where you're stuck.** || Questions which just copy coursework to us, without showing any of your own work, are not well-received. As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help].

Comment: Active high and active low just refers to the voltage levels present on the pins, but the truth table is the same for both.  For active low logical one / asserted is low voltage and logical zero / unasserted is high voltage.  For active high logic one / asserted is high voltage, and logical zero is low voltage.

Comment: Draw a truth table for one stage at a time. First do the decoder, then the AND gate, then for each mux, and lastly combine everything.